# Create Property Sheet in Frame Window

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I am using an MDI application. I want to create a property sheet inside Frame Window area as shown by arrow in image below:

[image: MDI Application]

I have seen examples where we can use ShowWindow() function after creating property sheet but it creates property sheet which is not embedded in frame window.

Can we create propertysheet on frame window only like other controls as static box etc?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Do you mean MDI tab page like visual studio? This link may help for you. [link1](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1438/CMDITabs), [link2](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/107/Window-Tabs-WndTabs-Add-In-for-DevStudio)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to embed a resizable property sheet to the view, please take a look at BCGSoft size(http://www.bcgsoft.com) - the latest BCGControlBar from  version shows how to do it:

http://www.bcgsoft.com/images/resizableform220.jpg

If you simply need a tabbed MDI windows, just create a Visual Studio-like application in MFC AppWizard (VS 2008 or later).

Hope, this helps.

Rob

Answer (score 0):

Adding `CMultiDocTemplate` instances solved my problem. Here is code snippet. This is part of ProjectName.cpp file:

```
BOOL CEmuDiagnosticsClientApp::InitInstance()
{
// InitCommonControlsEx() is required on Windows XP if an application
// manifest specifies use of ComCtl32.dll version 6 or later to enable
// visual styles.  Otherwise, any window creation will fail.
INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX InitCtrls;
InitCtrls.dwSize = sizeof(InitCtrls);
// Set this to include all the common control classes you want to use
// in your application.
InitCtrls.dwICC = ICC_WIN95_CLASSES;
InitCommonControlsEx(&InitCtrls);

CWinAppEx::InitInstance();

// Initialize OLE libraries
if (!AfxOleInit())
{
    AfxMessageBox(IDP_OLE_INIT_FAILED);
    return FALSE;
}
AfxEnableControlContainer();

//Added new code
{
    CMultiDocTemplate* pDocTemplate;
    pDocTemplate = new CMultiDocTemplate(IDR_STRING_LOGGINGWINDOW,
        RUNTIME_CLASS(CEmuDiagnosticsClientDoc),
        RUNTIME_CLASS(CChildFrame), // custom MDI child frame
        RUNTIME_CLASS(CLoggingWindow));
    if (!pDocTemplate)
        return FALSE;
    AddDocTemplate(pDocTemplate);
}
//End: Added new code

// Standard initialization
// If you are not using these features and wish to reduce the size
// of your final executable, you should remove from the following
// the specific initialization routines you do not need
// Change the registry key under which our settings are stored
// TODO: You should modify this string to be something appropriate
// such as the name of your company or organization
SetRegistryKey(_T("Local AppWizard-Generated Applications"));
LoadStdProfileSettings(4);  // Load standard INI file options (including MRU)

InitContextMenuManager();

InitKeyboardManager();

InitTooltipManager();
CMFCToolTipInfo ttParams;
ttParams.m_bVislManagerTheme = TRUE;
theApp.GetTooltipManager()->SetTooltipParams(AFX_TOOLTIP_TYPE_ALL,
    RUNTIME_CLASS(CMFCToolTipCtrl), &ttParams);

// Register the application's document templates.  Document templates
//  serve as the connection between documents, frame windows and views
CMultiDocTemplate* pDocTemplate;
pDocTemplate = new CMultiDocTemplate(IDR_STRING_SIGNALWINDOW,
    RUNTIME_CLASS(CEmuDiagnosticsClientDoc),
    RUNTIME_CLASS(CChildFrame), // custom MDI child frame
    RUNTIME_CLASS(CSignalWindow)); //Changed Code
if (!pDocTemplate)
    return FALSE;
AddDocTemplate(pDocTemplate);


// create main MDI Frame window
CMainFrame* pMainFrame = new CMainFrame;
if (!pMainFrame || !pMainFrame->LoadFrame(IDR_MAINFRAME))
{
    delete pMainFrame;
    return FALSE;
}
m_pMainWnd = pMainFrame;
// call DragAcceptFiles only if there's a suffix
//  In an MDI app, this should occur immediately after setting m_pMainWnd


// Parse command line for standard shell commands, DDE, file open
CCommandLineInfo cmdInfo;
ParseCommandLine(cmdInfo);

// Dispatch commands specified on the command line.  Will return FALSE if
// app was launched with /RegServer, /Register, /Unregserver or /Unregister.
if (!ProcessShellCommand(cmdInfo))
    return FALSE;
// The main window has been initialized, so show and update it
pMainFrame->ShowWindow(m_nCmdShow);
pMainFrame->UpdateWindow();

return TRUE;
}
```

In **//Added New code** section, created a new `CMultiDocTemplate` instance.     `CLoggingWindow` is the class which I wanted to display in frame window.
Another class `CSignalWindow` I also wanted to display which is modified in **//changed code** area.

Things to remember:
-Dialog which you want to display must be derived from CFormView, not CDialog.
-Changed dialog property: **Border -> None**,  **Style -> Child** and **all other properties to false.**